# Rails: Published On Date not Updating Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic blog setup on one of my apps.  Each `blog` has a boolean for whether it is `published` and then a date for when it is `published_on`.  The `published_on` is `nil` until it updates with `published` as `true`.  The controller logic is like this:

```
  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    @blog.user_id = current_user.id
    if @blog.published
      @blog.published_on = Time.now
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @blog.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And for update...

```
  def update
    if @blog.published && @blog.published_on.nil?
      @blog.published_on = Time.now
    end
    ...
  end
```

However, the update function doesn't update and I get a `undefined method 'strftime' for nil:NilClass` error for where it should display on the `show` page.  When I `rails c` it, the `published_on` didn't save.

What should I be putting instead of the `Time.now` logic I currently have in the controller.  It works fine with the `blog#create`, but something is going wrong in the `blog#update`.

Comment: Side note:I'd suggest calling it `published_at` as it's consistent with Rails convention of created_at and updated_at.

Comment: I think the controller might be the wrong place. You could implement a after_save callback in your model. There you can set the timestamp `self.published_on = DateTime.now if self.published`

Comment: @SimonFranzen Yes!  I always forget about the model!  This worked perfectly.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll happily select it.

Comment: Please see my answer. You also have to look if the published bool changed. Otherwise it will set the date every time you save the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the controller might be the wrong place. You could implement a after_save callback in your model. There you can set the timestamp `self.published_on = DateTime.now if self.published`

```
after_save :set_published_at

def set_published_at 
  self.published_on = DateTime.now if self.published
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DateTime.now instead of Time.now? They are different classes and I'm not sure a datetime attribute can be directly assigned to a Time object.

```
@blog.published_on = DateTime.now
```